# How to make starting a UiApp by a group of users easy?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

After opening Gmail or Google Drive you see the google bar (containing the Google logo, a searchbox and clickable button for apps, notification of unread messages, sharing and about) on top of the window.

I want to put a put a button for starting my UiApp (build with GAS) there as well.
Is this possible (and how) ?

Several users will have read access to the google drive. I want those users to be able to start my UiApp from a button in google bar as well. What should I do (and what should they do) to make that possible?

If this is not possible, where can I put my UiApp best so users can start it easy?

My application is NOT intended to be accessible by other people except the ones I provided access to my Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can accomplish this by leveraging the Gadgets section of the Gmail API to accomplish this as detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/gadgets_overview). I've seen this type of Gadget added by a Chrome Extension before but not directly from Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use the "New" button, and publish a script to the Chrome Web Store.  Then your app would be in the drop down list of the "New" button.  The problem with that, is that the general public could see the app.  I'm assuming you don't want that.

If you want an easily accessible central location for users, you could create a website with Google App Engine.  You can get a free domain name of

www.mySiteName.appspot.com

It would be easier for users to get there than the URL of your Apps Script.